# For Linux platform, why should I build Python from source instead of pre-built binaries?

Tags: python, linux

I am creating a docker image which is going to be based on `buildpack-deps:stretch` based image. I am told that it is preferred to install a Python version which was built from source instead of installing pre-built binaries.

**Question**: Why is it preferred for Python to be built from source?

1. I read some articles talk about able to get latest patches etc., but
   that does not make much sense to me since the pre-built binaries
   would also have the patches after some testing is done. You ideally
   do not want to take in source code which is not tested and build and
   use it. Am I missing something in my argument?
2. If Python has pre-built binaries for `debian:stretch`, in my scenario why should I
   be prefer to build from source instead of pre-built binaries?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can I know what you try to achieve here? did you following any guideline? I prefer the stable releases rather than build from source, but it depends on the features/requirements what you want to achieve

Answer (score 2):

> I am told that it is preferred to install a Python version which was built from source instead of installing pre-built binaries.

Without a qualification why, that was not a very meaningful suggestion. There are reasons to go either way, so I'll list those instead.

Reasons to use system packages:

- automatic system updates will take care of emergency updates and security patching in a standard way - you can save a lot of time
- you can be fairly confident that everything's compiled and distributed in a consistent way without breaking applications which rely on a given version (for example 3.5)
- not managing your own compilation saves you time in both development and in build/release process
- you don't have to track upstream point-releases using a custom process

Reasons to compile yourself:

- if you want to rely on a specific patch not included upstream
- if you need to use new version, not released in your distro

In general, unless you can specifically say what you're going to gain by compiling from sources, understand you're committing to doing that on every future release, and hopefully define how you're going to automate it and who's going to do the work/maintenance - I don't see a reason to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @viraptor's excellent advice for installation on systems, containerization adds some things which change the equation a bit.

For any container, building it yourself ensures more knowledge of what's going into it, which usually means a more secure container. It's also usually very easy to use the more minimal alpine containers (or to port an application to them) which means there's less surface area for security holes in the first place, and they're physically smaller which means less local maintenance and lower hosting costs.

Python can easily be built on alpine, there are even [official containers](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/) maintained by the Docker company, whose source can be forked to build your own. Dockerhub will even build it for you from a GitHub repository if you configure it to.